# Map DOM element to memory object in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building a basic grid component with Angular 6. The grid itself is a `<table>`, with a `<thead>` for the header and a `<tbody>` section, where there are multiple rows. Each row has a fixed first column (which has de ID of the row), a dynamic number of 'positions' and a fixed last column (which holds an action combo button). Each of the positions contain a list of objects, dragged from an external tree component. All the rows, the positions and the list of objects inside them are generated from a DB, and displayed using `*ngFor` in the component template.

To make it clear, here's an schema of the grid:

[image: Table representation]

The grid is built in this way:

```
<table #mainGrid>
  <thead>
    [...]
  </thead>

  <tbody (contextmenu)="showContextMenu($event)">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of objectGrid; let i=index">
      <td>{{ i }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let position of row.positions">
        <ul class="object--list">
          <li class="object--list--item" *ngFor="let object of position.objects">
            {{ object.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td><!-- CODE FOR THE ACTION BUTTON --></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each object has several actions associated to it (f.i. 'Delete', 'Locate in tree', 'Edit', etc) that must be chosen using the right button of the mouse. I'd like to avoid attaching an event handler to each object because sometimes the grid will contain more than 700 objects, so my idea is to attach only 1 `contextmenu` handler to the `<tbody>` (to disable right clicking on the table header) and use logic to find out the object where the user right clicked.

So far, I can use the event `path` property to identify the row, cell and the object (`li` element) where the right click occured. But now I'd like to know an elegant way of associating univocally the clicked `li` element to the position of the array that generated it.

For example, if I right click on the object 'Object 1.4.2', I'd like to get the reference to `this.objectGrid[0].positions[3].objects[1]`.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a safe way of doing it, so I've ended up adding the event handler to each of the objects that need it. So far, the performance for a grid with 500+ elements is pretty good, but I'm studying how to implement a virtualization to the grid component to load only the rows displayed on screen.